# Why does the renormalizable theory have only those particles with helicity less than or equal to 1?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, renormalization, helicity, higher-spin

Let the helicity operator be $$\frac{P \cdot J}{P^0}$$ with an eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then why do renormalizable theories have $|\lambda| \le 1?$ (in general dimensions or in 4D?)

Also, what is the kinetic term of a spin-$s$ particle? For example, for spin-2 particle.

Comment: @G.Smith in p.31 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1491

Comment: Your second question should be posted separately. We have a one-question-per-post rule on this site. Thanks.

Comment: @G.Smith i guess the second question is related to the first question by counting the engineering dimensions of the kinetic term.

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-spin_theory) due diligence.